# where can i get the google play SDK for admob?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I recently sign up for admob by google and i am trying to add it into my app but able to do it due to the missing google sdk.

I have read guide found online but all seen to be outdated.

can someone assist me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement Google Play Services in your app.

Follow the guide from Android: [AdMob Android Guides](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

If you are still using Eclipse or Netbeans, follow the guide to download play services via the sdk manager.
Then, check out the arrows, to find the play services project in your download path.
In my case, it's on "ANDROID_SDK_HOME\extras\google\google_play_services".

[image: Google Play Services - Android SDK Manager]

--
Quoting google, the standalone sdk can no longer be used:

> Attention Android developers: On August 1, 2014, Google Play stopped
>   accepting new or updated apps that use the old standalone Google
>   Mobile Ads SDK v6.4.1 or lower. You must upgrade to the Google Play
>   version of the Mobile Ads SDK.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have tried that guide earlier when i sign up for admod. i try the sdk manager to find the sdk but can find it at all. The admob need the google Repository but i jus cant find it using the sdk manager or use eclipse installation manager

Comment: I have just try agin but only see android support library under the extra folder in the android sdk manager.

Comment: May be its already installed and "Installed checkbox is OFF". Or your package list is out of date (press Packages -> Reload)

Comment: Gero i try that i have enable those i installed to appear. I have taken a pic but dont seen to able to upload a pic in here

Comment: Sorry, but adding play services to your app is off this topic. You need to open a new thread here or at Android developers group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-developers)

Answer (score 0):

For those who like need to get the Google play SDK
you will need to have the latest Eclispe and the lastest android sdk

i was runnning on version 22 hence i having the issue of not able to get the google play sdk